# i have a sql select query error dont know what the right syntax is

Tags: java, mysql

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       String sql="select * from account where Username and Password=(?,?)"; //I think here is some error but dont know what it is

       try
       {
       stm=con.prepareStatement(sql);
       stm.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
       stm.setString(2,jPasswordField1.getText());
       rs=stm.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next())
       {
       rs.close();
       stm.close();
       setVisible(false);
       Loading ob =new Loading();
       ob.setVisible(true);
       }
       else
       {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect username and password");
       }
       }
       catch(SQLException exp)
       {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp);
       }
       finally
       {
       try
       {
       rs.close();
       stm.close();
       }
       catch(SQLException exp)
       {
       exp.printStackTrace();
       }
       }


    }
```

Comment: What is the error? Please add that to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show the error messages you received.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis this is the error  
parameter index out of range (1>number of parameter 0 )

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql="select * from account where Username and Password=(?,?)";
```

Well I'm no SQL expert but I think it should be:

```
String sql="select * from account where Username = ? and Password=?";
```

I hope you plan on asking a question every time you have a little problem. You can't just guess what the SQL syntax is, so you need to buy a book or find a tutorial.

Maybe the [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) can give you some general information.

Comment: @AashishKalia define "not working". You will either get an SQL syntax error or you will get data in a ResultSet or you will get no data in a ResultSet.. Why don't you start with a simple query like "Select * from Account" and see what happens.

Comment: what did you mean @AashishKalia your query is not correct you don't even show us your error this is the correct syntax of your query maybe you get another problem

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
WHERE username=?  AND  password=?
```

Comment: yes i am trying to get username and password  but may be i think there is so syntax error in my code in select query possibly WHERE username=?  AND  password=?

Comment: parameter index out of range (1>number of parameter 0 )

Answer (score -2):

Use below query:

```
"select * from account where Username=? and Password=?;"
```

Comment: How does this add anything that @camickr has not already shown?

Comment: (1-) this was suggested 9 minutes earlier. No need to clutter the forum with the same suggestion.

Comment: @camickr : hvnt refreshed the page.. sorry.

Answer (score -3):

You should use simple `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement`, and put the user and pass field text in your query.

This sample code may help you:

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "select * from table where Username='"+user.getText()+"' AND Password='"+pass.getText()+"'";
res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jdbc/9238/jdbc-statement-injection#t=201705062129495002262

Comment: (1-), In addition to the above comment, a PreparedStatement will work just fine when coded properly. It is far easier to maintain and is less error prone. There is no reason to use String concatenation.

Comment: But i think, he is a beginner, so  he dont need to focus on security right now

Comment: @SalmanSabir, `But i think, he is a beginner,` - that is even more of a reason to use a PreparedStatement.   Reread my comment. A PreparedStaement is easier for a beginner because you don't need to worry about all the proper delimeters. Therefore you are less likely to make an SQL syntax error. There is no reason to use a regular statement. A PreparedStatement is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Oh really, i thought regular Statement is easier than Prepared

Comment: @camickr help me out please. I get same error everytime  
parameter index out of range (1>number of parameter 0 ) when i try to click on my login account button

Comment: When you getting the string from sql in while loop start the index from 1 not 0, or you can also put the column name as string